# Variable significance for assessment results

Tags: multivariate-analysis

I am trying to analyze multiple variables of our student population as it comes to assessment outcomes. I have the assessment change score and demographic information such as (race, sex, age, program, # of programs, time of service, # of services). I am trying to ascertain which variables are significant to the change scores, and how significant.

Comment: Why not just regression, with the change score as the DV?

Answer (score 0):

Correlation grids are usually good starting points. They allow you to see if there is any similar trends between independent variables and specific distribution (log normal, normal, binomial, etc.)